# Upper span is moving the lower span...Why is that

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have this [page](http://dev.petmate.com/our-other-brands) that i am working on and as you can see there are four images...if you look at the lower left booda...it has two links view Booda dog and view Booda cats. If you click the top one the bottom link moves to the left...i for the life of me cant figure out how to fix this. I am using position relitive. Here is some of my css

```
.booda a.button_below {
        left: 107px;
    position: relative;
    top: 64px;
}

.entry .booda a.button {
 position: relative;
    right: 13px;
    top: 31px;
}
```

there is other css if you view it in firebug

any help will be greatly appreciated ...thanks in advance

Comment: does this happen on all browsers?

Comment: all the mac browsers (Firefox, safari, chrome) the same issue happens, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly is going on, but changing the bottom button class from `button_below` to `button` and giving it `clear:right` fixed it for me.

Hope this gets you closer to a solution!

Comment: awesome...that did it...thanks again...what is the clear right doing

Comment: I have no idea, I had a tough time sifting through the CSS and was in a bit of a rush posting (gf was getting home), but I'm glad it helped. I hate to leave you hanging but I've got to run again, good luck!

Comment: If you mean "What does `clear:right` ***do***?", it makes sure there are no floated elements to the right of it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like it has to do with the text size changing when the link is highlighted.

When the upper span is selected the span is enlarged and the bottom span is shifted to align properly.

Try aligning the spans on the right instead of the left.

EDIT: To align a span to the right you can add this to your current span tags.

`position: absolute;
right: 0;`

But you have to switch to an absolute position. To continue using relative positioning you can wrap the spans in a single container that has `position: relative`

Comment: tried that and it didnt work...its still there so you can see

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `position: relative` with `top` and `right`. Use `position: relative` on their container and then `position: absolute` on those `span`s.

Comment: refresh the page...i tried you approach and not sure what css is needed to make this approach work

Comment: Ok, so now you just have to reformat the rest of the CSS. You want `display: block`, and to adjust the top/right and width/height properties.